# How to override NumPy's ndarray implicit Boolean? (i.e. the __bool__ function)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, numpy-ndarray

Before the argument begins, I'll explain a use case. tl;dr: a read-only library checks for implicit Booleanness.

I've overridden Keras's train_step to only take one argument (for a GAN). This is fine for training data. However, when I add validation data, Keras has a check:

```
if validation_data:
  val_x, val_y, val_sample_weight = (
    data_adapter.unpack_x_y_sample_weight(validation_data))
```

and NumPy of course raises

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Normally, validation_data is a list, tuple, etc. and this check works out fine.
I don't want to change the library's source code so my best idea is to override the implicit booleanness of numpy.ndarray

However, subclassing like

```
class np_array_falsifiable(np.ndarray):
    def __bool__(self):
        return self.size
```

raises

```
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 6301
```

I'll appreciate and accept any answer to get around this.

Comment: why on earth are you overriding `__init__` at all....? You are doing it incorrectly, but you could probably just *remove it* unless I'm missing something obvious

Comment: That being said, this sounds like a really bad idea. Why not jsut convert your numpy.ndarray to a list, e.g. `validation_data.tolist()`?

Comment: also, you probably want to return `self.size` or possibly `self.any(None)` or `self.all(None)`. What is `.length`?

Comment: Removing ```__init__``` raised the same error. Converting to a list will not allow NumPy calls of the list and Keras will treat the validation_data as several inputs (with incorrect shapes) instead of one.

Comment: *How are you initializing your object*? Have you [read the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html) for the `numpy.ndarray` constructor?

Comment: self.size is correct---I updated it. I also removed ```__init__``` for conciseness. I found a work around in my use case by overriding Keras.model functions. But this issue could still occur in other libraries so I'll leave it up.

Comment: The data is initialized by mapping pd.Dataframe().to_numpy() to 3 axes using sliding windows.

Comment: The first possitional argument of `np.ndarray` (i.e the class init) is `shape`.  np.array` is not the class init, but rather a factory function.